# Bootstrap class to remove background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, bootstrap-4

Is there any bootstrap class which can remove a background image from the div?

I have this style in css:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
```

and i want to remove it like this:

```
bg-img-none
```

or something else,

can somebody tell me how to do it?

Comment: have you read in the docs if exist a class for this? why you don't write your own class?

Answer (score 0):

‍‍‍No, but you can add it yourself.

```css
.bg-img-none {
    background-image: none !important;
}
.bg-none {
    background: none !important;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `!important`. Just make sure to have the right selectivity and order of css properties.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `bg-transparent` to make the background transparent. this will not make the background as null but change the transparency of area to 0.
you can check out it at [bootstrap documnetation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/colors/).This documentation is for colour backgrounds.
**OR**
you can add a custom CSS to remove the background

```
.bg-img-none{
background-image: none;
background: none;
}
```